# Sort an array of tuples in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift3, tuples

Hi I have the following

```
class MyClass {
  var myString: String?
}

var myClassList = [String: MyClass]()
```

I would like to sort this array alphabetically by the myString variable in Swift 3 any pointers?

Comment: `myClassList` is a dictionary not an array. I recommend you get the data structures correct before moving on to sorting.

Comment: `myClassList.sorted{($0.value.myString ?? "") < ($1.value.myString ?? "")}`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, you have a dictionary, not tuples.
However, Dictionaries do indeed have a `sorted(by:)` method that you can use to sort an array of Key/Value pair tuples.  Here's an example:

```
var m: [String: Int] = ["a": 1]
let n = m.sorted(by: { (first: (key: String, value: Int), second: (key: String, value: Int)) -> Bool in
  return first.value > second.value
})
```

That's expanded to show the full signature of the closure, however easily shorthanded to:

```
let n = m.sorted(by: {
  return $0.value > $1.value
})
```

Additionally, you can also perform other enumerations over Dictionaries

```
m.forEach { (element: (key: String, value: Int)) in
  print($0.value)
}
```

All of this is due to the Collection and sequence protocol hierarchies in Swift, they're some pretty nice abstractions.

Comment: if you remove the parentheses you can omit the `by:`. You can also omit the `return`keyword. BTW He said he wants to sort by myString property

Comment: Right in this case I wanted the strings alphabetized.

Comment: @LeoDabus Check xcode, Dictionaries only have `sorted(by:)`, meaning you can't omit the `by` when enclosing in parens, you can however if you're using trailing closure syntax (Though stylistically that isn't preferred for things like sort/map/filter)

Answer (score 3):

Cool problem! Though i'd like to point out first that `[String: MyClass]` is a Dictionary and not at Tupule.

Swift does, however, support Tupules. The syntax for your tupule would look like so:

```
var tupule: (String, MyClass) = (foo, bar)
```

You would then need to make an Array of them:

```
var tupules:[(String, MyClass)] = [(foo, bar), (up, dog)]
```

Then you could sort that array:

```
tupules.sort({ $0[1].myString > $1[1].myString })
```

though you should probably define a more robust sort mechanism.

These are the contents of the sort closure:

> **$0** is the one of the objects for which needs to be compared, **$1** is the other.
>   **$0[1]** and **$1[1]** accesses the objects' 1 index, in this case, as defined in your tupule, it is your custom object **MyClass**

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can sort a dictionary, it returns an array of tuples (key, value)

Answer (score 0):

Swift version 5.2.4

```swift
let arr = [(0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 3)] // -> [(3, 1), (1, 2), (4, 3), (2, 4), (0, 5)]
let sorted = arr.sorted{ $0.1 < $1.1 }
```