# Swift 3 sorting an array of tuples

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift3, tuples

I found these answers:

[Sort an array of tuples in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112955/sort-an-array-of-tuples-in-swift-3)
[How to sort an Array of Tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234507/how-to-you-sort-an-array-of-tuples)

But I'm still having issues. Here is my code:

```
var countsForLetter:[(count:Int, letter:Character)] = []
...
countsForLetter.sorted(by: {$0.count < $1.count})
```

Swift 3 wanted me to add the by: and now it says that the result of the call to sorted:by is unused.

I'm new to swift 3. Sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are getting that warning because `sorted(by...` returns a new, sorted version of the array you call it on.  So the warning is pointing out the fact that you're not assigning it to a variable or anything.  You could say:

```
countsForLetter = countsForLetter.sorted(by: {$0.count < $1.count})
```

I suspect that you're trying to "sort in place", so in that case you could change `sorted(by` to `sort(by` and it would just sort `countsForLetter` and leave it assigned to the same variable.

Answer (score 8):

Sorted() returns a new array, it does not sort in place.

you can use :

```
countsForLetter  = countsForLetter.sorted(by: {$0.count < $1.count})
```

or

```
countsForLetter.sort(by: {$0.count < $1.count})
```